# ruby on rails controller not passing object when layout is false

Tags: ruby-on-rails, layout, view, controller

I'm new to Ruby on Rails and I have following issue:
If have a method in controller:

```
def showbudgets
render :layout => false
username = session[:username]
time = Time.new
@budgets = Budget.findAll(username, time.year)
end
```

I'm getting two records in @budgets as I checked it by using logger.debug

I have the following view:

```
<h2>Listing Budgets</h2>
<% if @budgets != nil %>
<table style="width:500px">
<tr>
<th>Year</th>
<th>Month</th>
<th>Amount</th>
</tr>
<% @budgets.each do |budget| %>
<tr>
<td><%= budget.budgetyear %></td>
<td><%= budget.budgetmonth %></td>
<td><%= budget.amount %></td>
</tr>
<% end %>
</table>
<% else %>
<br/>
No budgets set...
<% end %>
```

I'm using ajax request so I don't want a layout applied on my view
Now if I remove the line

```
render :layout => false
```

it displays the records otherwise not

Answer (score 1):

View is being render when you call your 'render' method. This means, that that inside the view there is no @budgets variable defined, hence it will return null.

You need to reorder your action, so render is at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You could use respond_to for different formats of response. code maybe:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html {}           # html response
  format.json { @budgets } # json as a api or something
  format.js   {}           # js response
end
```

For js response, you should create a action_name.js.erb file in correspond views folder and put the js code you want to execute in it.